# How to overload operator[] for indexing the shared_ptr elements of a custom vector class?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, shared-ptr, square-bracket

Currently, I'm creating my own vector class, and I like to create instances of any class via shared pointers. So, is there a way to overload `operator[]` in order to achieve the following code?

```cpp
class myVector {
    public:
        myVector(/*some params*/);
        ~myVector();

        // Some kind of overloading of operator []

        // Some other code

    private:
        // private container array
        double* vec;

        // Some other code
};

int main ()
{
    std::shared_ptr<myVector> sp = std::shared_ptr<myVector>(new myVector(/*some params*/));

    double val = sp[1];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` can be used to store an array, and then you can acces the elements through `operator[]`. If the `shared_ptr` doesn't store an array, as in your case, you can't rely on the operator to be declared at all.

Comment: You would be able to write `(*sp)[1]` (dereferencing and then accessing an index) if you write an `operator[]` overload. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators especially regarding the array subscript operator.

Comment: @NathanPierson That'd be `(*sp)[1]`.

Comment: FWIW, having a pointer to a "managed container" is normally not what you want.

Comment: @krisz Thanks for the operator precedence correction

Comment: Change the `double* vec` to a `shared_ptr` then just use `myVector` by value

Answer (score 1):

You could declare the `[]` operator for your `myVector` class as follows (returning a reference to the element so you have read and write access):

```cpp
double& operator [] (int i)
{
    return vec[i];
}
```

You can then use this operator on the object pointed to by the `shared_ptr` by first dereferencing that. Here's a runnable example, where I've added some 'dummy' code to the constructor just to make it do something:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class myVector {
public:
    myVector(/*some params*/) {
        vec = new double[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) vec[i] = 3 * i;
    }
    ~myVector() {
        delete[] vec;
    }
    double& operator [] (int i) {
        return vec[i];
    }
 private:
    double* vec;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<myVector> sp = std::shared_ptr<myVector>(new myVector(/*some params*/));
    double val = (*sp)[6];
    std::cout << val << std::endl;
    (*sp)[4] = 312;
    std::cout << (*sp)[4] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can overload the operator for the class the following way

```
double & operator []( size_t i )
{
    return vec[i];
}
```

and

```
const double & operator []( size_t i ) const
{
    return vec[i];
}
```

and call it like

```
std::shared_ptr<myVector> sp = std::shared_ptr<myVector>(new myVector(/*some params*/));

//...

std::cout << ( *sp )[i] << '\n';
```

Comment: @AdrianMole They are not differ only in their return  types.

Answer (score 0):

I would not do this in real application. But just for demonstration, one possibility to achieve what you want (at least technically) is to derive from std::shared_ptr and there declare the index operator. For ex:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class myshared_ptr;

template <class T >
class myshared_ptr<vector<T>> : public shared_ptr<vector<T>>
{
public:
    using elem_type = vector<T>;
    using shared_ptr<elem_type>::shared_ptr;
    using shared_ptr<elem_type>::operator*;
    using shared_ptr<elem_type>::get;
    
    typename elem_type::value_type& operator[](size_t idx)
    {
        return (*get())[idx];
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    auto p = myshared_ptr<vector<int>>(new vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4});
    cout << p[2] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LE7vonZktTIFsUw2)